# Getting Error While doing pagination in angular 4

Tags: angular4-forms

I am new to angular 4. I am working in pagination using angular 4.I ahve installed "npm install ngx-pagination --save". I followed the instruction which was in internet. But I am getting error like "The pipe 'paginate' could not be found ("
                
                
                    ]game of games | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 2, currentPage: p }">
                        {{i}}
    "): ng:///ActivityChartModule/ActivityComponent.html@235:32
    'pagination-controls' is not a known element:". I tried More. Can any one help me to comeout from this problem. Below are my code,

```
app.module.ts
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';
imports: [NgxPaginationModule]

in component.ts
p: number = 1;


    games = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "DOTA 2",
            "genre": "Strategy"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "AOE 3",
            "genre": "Strategy"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "GTA 5",
            "genre": "RPG"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Far Cry 3",
            "genre": "Action"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "GTA San Andreas",
            "genre": "RPG"
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Hitman",
            "genre": "Action"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "name": "NFS MW",
            "genre": "Sport"
        }, {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Fifa 16",
            "genre": "Sport"

        }, {
            "id": "9",
            "name": "NFS Sen 2",
            "genre": "Sport"

        }, {
            "id": "10",
            "name": "Witcher Assasins on King",
            "genre": "Adventure"
        }

    ];

in component.html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search">
        </nav>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let game of games | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 2, currentPage: p }">
                    <td>{{i}}</td>
                    <td>{{game.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{game.genre}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p($event)"></pagination-controls>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have already import **NgxPaginationModule** into app.module.ts, I think it is because you need to restart your project after npm install.
Try ctrl+c and ng serve to restart it again.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem, you need to include in your **module.ts** following code:

```
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ NgxPaginationModule ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in angular-core

and

schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ] ----add it in your @NgModule({})

refer this link: https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/12/angular2-template-parse-errors-add-custom_elements_schema-to-the-ngmodule-schemas/

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and did not face the error you faced. However, the variable p used is actually an event and not a number[].

Replace the table and pagination-control element as per below in app.component.html:

```
 <table class="table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Genre</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let game of games | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 2, currentPage: p }">
              <td>{{game.id}}</td>
              <td>{{game.name}}</td>
              <td>{{game.genre}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
      <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
  </div>
```

Also, declaring p within app.component.ts isn't required as its the paginationApi that gets used internally.

Side note: The error you are getting suggests that the ngx-pagination is not installed successfully. Please check if you have the ngx-pagination folder copied within your project's node_modules folder successfully.

Demo: https://angular-ijtgcv.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of "import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';"
in app.module.ts
It works out for me

Answer (score 0):

after importing NgxPaginationModule to app.module.ts and stop the local server 'npm update' worked for me !

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/63926342/2227743